# Unittesting web applications

Tags: python, web

I am developing a very simple web application in python using the bottle microframework and I was wondering if there are frameworks that can rigorously aid in testing the application.

Comment: Are you using a particular framework? They may have documents on testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This StackOverflow link might be of use:

[Practicing BDD with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231371/practicing-bdd-with-python)

Here's a link to the mentioned [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html?highlight=doctest#module-doctest).