# Python unit testing for existing project to set up BDD

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-2.7, bdd

We might be interested in starting to incorporate a unit test suite to our project, which is coded in Python (and it uses Redis, PostgreSQL and some third-party libraries, if that bears into the solution).  The benefits we want to achieve are:

1. Once the project is up to speed, we want to be able to specify new behavior quickly and efficiently, to help improve communication and team productivity.  Read: **We want BDD, but have already started coding without it**.
2. Excellent textual support (i.e. the tests can be read almost as natural text), so as to make it **easier to write and read tests**.
3. Ability to **automatically run tests** (at the very least, to be able to include the running in a Bash script or something like that).  We use Windows and Linux for development, and Linux servers, so Linux support is our primary requirement.
4. **Integration with github**.  I don't know if it is possible, but I've seen some projects in github which have a "Passing" or "Failing" status on them and it would be great to have that for our project.

What are good tools / libraries that can help us do this, and, most importantly, what are good ways to incorporate BDD into a Python project?

Thank you very much!  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Practicing BDD with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231371/practicing-bdd-with-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quite liked:

- http://heynemann.github.com/pyvows
- https://github.com/rlisagor/freshen
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/behave

You may find more by searching:

```
pip search bdd
```

Comment: Behave looks like something we might want to look into. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I searched high and low for something small, literate, and non-magical to do testing in Python, and could find nothing, so I came up with https://github.com/kislyuk/ensure.

You'll need to use another test framework to structure your tests around it (personally, I'm quite content with unittest), and it doesn't have github integration, which I think you're better off using Travis for.