# Python testing tool like Behat in the PHP

Tags: php, python, selenium, bdd, behat

I am trying to test a web-application, using python,
I am new in python so don't know much Python testing tools, i have written tests in **Selenium/Pink/Behat in the PHP world,** Now i have to use python for Behavior-Driven-Development (BDD),
I have been looked Google, but I couldn't really get a definitive answer. can any one please suggest me best python testing tool, like Behat.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231371/practicing-bdd-with-python

Answer (score -1):

Try using Unittesting such as http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: Is that really BDD specific?

Comment: yes browser based BDD testing.

Comment: I haven't done any BDD programming but as for testing code it works, just a sugestion

Comment: that's more like phpunit not behat